# Enable-SPFeature fails with Url containing spaces

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

SharePoint 2010 PowerShell

If Url (Sub Site ) contains Spaces Enable-SPFeature fails,

Tried,
1) Enable-SPFeature –Identity 8c7cfc9f-a19a-4604-8b1b-db11d77d3d0b –URL
 "Complete Server  + Sub Site with spaces"
Results : 
Enable-SPFeature : 0x80070002Th
ere is no Web named "/Hello+World".
At line:1 char:17
+ Enable-SPFeature <<<<  -Identity 8c7cfc9f-a19a-4604-8b1b-db11d77d3d0b -Url "h
ttp://vm7491/Hello World"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...etEnableFeature:
   SPCmdletEnableFeature) [Enable-SPFeature], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletEnableFe
   ature

Answer (score 1):

Replace any spaces with %20 in the URL

Answer (score 0):

You should always use ' or " when working with strings that contains spaces in PowerShell.

Ex. 'http://myisteurl.com/sites/something/My sub site'